# How do i append attributed text to a UItextview

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to append attributed text to an UItextview but it causes strange codes to appear instead of the original receiveView.text, the message appended afterwards is however shown correctly. Here is how i do it:

```
    //receiveView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@",receiveView.text,message];
    [receiveView setAttributedText: [ansiEscapeHelper attributedStringWithANSIEscapedString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",receiveView.attributedText,message]]];
```

And here is what gets printed instead of the original receiveView.text. How do i succeed in appending attributed text to the already existing attributed text?

[image: This is what gets printed instead of the original message]

Comment: do you already have some text in you `receiveView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",receiveView.attributedText,message]` you're converting the description of the attributed string into an `NSString`, appending another string and then setting it to the text view.

Instead, use `NSMutableAttributedString` to create your attributed string.

Comment: my helper converts strings to attributed string, but I do see my error now, im mixing strings with attributedstrings, should do something like:

    [receiveView setAttributedText: [NSAttributedString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",receiveView.attributedText,[ansiEscapeHelper attributedStringWithANSIEscapedString:message]]];